# Remove last character (regardless of what it is) from one column in a csv file

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with the below... I need to keep the UPC column at 13 characters (removing the last character)  How would I do this in powershell.  tried trimend, trim, trimstart, nothing works since it pulls out all numbers that I put in the trim statement, not just the last one.

```
ZONE     UPC                TPR_SALES

10       12345678901234     10.00

12       43210987655421     20.00

10       23432654654646     30.00

10       67356753677777     1.00

13       86753098675309     0.50
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the substring() method:

```
('12345678901234').substring(0,13)
1234567890123
```

in this example the first argument is starting position, and the second is number of characters to include.

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing and export the file, you could also try something like this to remove the last character. However, `substring()` is better if you know the exact length you want.

```
$_.UPC = $_.UPC -replace '(\w)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

@mjolinor has a good suggestion, but Just be careful, if the column is not at least 13 characters, the substring message will through an error. One powershell exclusive method I use is `-join $string[0..12]`. It is probably more computationally intensive. As it has to expand the string to an array, enumerate an array on integers, then Jon the array to a string, but no exceptin is thrown when the string is shorter than your desired length